# Win8.1 booterror after moving efi(boot) partition

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I moved the recovery, the boot and the reserved partition of my win8.1 installation on my disk with mini tool partition wizard, like I did once before.
I restarted windows but now it won't start anymore, uefi boot starts, mb logo is shown, hdd is doing something but then this blue screen with the sad smiley ":(" is shown for half a second and then win8.1 restarts.
Safe Boot doesn't work either. bcdedit shows a beautiful config, no errors here. Win8.1 repair only says "Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC".

I just don't know what went wrong while moving, everything looks pretty. Does anyone know what can I try to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would reverse what you did personally.

Comment: I moved the boot partition before without problems, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Without the ability to even boot into Safe Mode your options are limited.  I would at least try my suggestion.

Comment: moved everything back, even rebuild my bcd, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFI refers to boot loader files using, in part, the EFI System Partition's (ESP's) GUID value. When you moved the ESP, that value might have changed, rendering the NVRAM-based references invalid. If so, you should be able to restore it in various ways, one of which is:

1. Prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Boot the rEFInd medium. rEFInd should detect the Windows boot loader.
3. Launch Windows from rEFInd. It's conceivable that the Windows boot loader will fail for reasons akin to the firmware's problems, though. If so, this procedure won't work.
4. If you're lucky and this procedure enables you to boot to Windows, you should be able to fix it by opening an Administrator Command Prompt window and typing the following command:

.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Note that I can't guarantee that this will work, but it's worth trying. At the very least, it shouldn't make matters worse.